# pip3 fails to install dependencies of openai-quickstart-python

Tags: python, pip, openai-api

I try to run this tutorial openai-quickstart-python, starting from a clean ubuntu docker machine, everything up-to-date. But pip3 fails.

```
$ docker run ubuntu:latest bash
$ apt update
$ apt install -y git python3-pip python3 python3.10-venv
$ pip install -U setuptools
$ pip install -U pip
$ python3 --version  # Python 3.10.6
$ pip3 --version     # pip 23.1.2 

$ git clone https://github.com/openai/openai-quickstart-python.git
$ cd openai-quickstart-python
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
unstructured 0.6.8 requires certifi>=2022.12.07, but you have certifi 2021.10.8 which is incompatible.

$ python3 -m pip install "certifi~=2022.12.07"
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi~=2022.12.07 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi~=2022.12.07
```

Is there a better package manager for python?
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error didn't state `certifi~=2022.12.07`. So to fix this, just change the dependency to `certifi>=2022.12.07`, which works just fine on my machine.